Why aren't accelerating frames (Rindler coordinates) curved?
If an accelerating frame is indistinguishable from a uniform gravitational field, how come Rindler coordinates live in flat spacetime while gravity curves spacetime.

The equivalence principle says acceleration is gravity and gravity is curvature, hence acceleration is curvature. Only curvature scalars are zero in tbe Rindler spacetime, but curvature is a tensor, not scalar, and components of a tensor depend on coordinates. So the claim that the Rindler spacetime is flat is false. It is asymptotically the same spacetime as near a black hole horizon, very far from flat.

Regarding the title of the post: Not all sources of acceleration needs to be due to curvature of spacetime. Eg. : Take accelerating charged particle in presence of an Electro-Magnetic field, or let's say a bob attached to a spring undergoing simple-harmonic motion, or friction experienced on a rough surface, drag forces , collision of particles - in all these cases the acceleration is non-gravitational in nature. An accelerating frame would then mean a coordinate frame attached to such an accelerating particle. Since this is not an inertial frame anymore, the basis vectors of such a frame could vary with time and space giving rise to non-zero Christoffel symbols. Rindler coordinates refers to one such frame describing the motion of an uniformly accelerating particle in a flat space-time...therefore, no gravity. The notion of gravity is really at the level of curvature, and it is important to note that non-zero Christoffel symbols does not necessarily mean non-zero Curvature, though the converse is true.
Also a small clarification regarding the equivalence principle : an accelerating frame is indistinguishable from gravitational field only locally, due to the possibility of defining the Riemann normal coordinates. Even in this case, the Christoffel symbols vanish at a point but the curvature does not. You can think of such normal coordinates defined in Rindler spacetime, but then it turns out that it can be extended globally for all points because of zero intrinsic curvature. And then the analytical extension of it to all the four wedges gives you the full Minkowski space-time

I see, that makes sense. I suppose since gravity doesn’t actually cause proper acceleration it wouldn’t lead to rhindler coordinates anyways. Other sources of acceleration like you mention would however.

yeah. although gravity doesn't produce the proper acceleration, it can produce relative acceleration b/w adjacent geodesics : these are essentially the tidal forces and relative frame dragging effect...all produced due to total intrinsic curvature.

@safesphere I'm answering here: I didn't understand what you mean by gradient of time dilation precisely. But it is also not clear what u mean by acceleration: the g in Newtonian gravity can be thought of as part of Christoffel symbols in geodesic equation - so u need non-trivial metric. Uniform weyl curvature will have a non-trivial metric and so a non-zero g. But in Newtonian approximation, you can argue the same from the geodesic deviation equation in which case u will have the tidal acceleration.  Another way to think is that there will be non-trivial curvature invariant for uniform weyl..

...so u can't say there is no gravity which would be the case for flat spacetime (but it has trivial invariants). Those asides, the interpretation u gave about weyl and Ricci tensors are correct. You can also think of it from an optical pov: the Ricci tensor produces pure focussing of geodetic light rays, Weyl tensor causes astigmatic focusing - i.e produces shear. So evidently the relative separation between two points on adjacent light rays evolve with time and it's not uniform.

Curved space describes  tidal forces. Tidal forces are  when the local ${\bf g}$ varies from place to place, and so gravity tries  to change the shape of an object  in addition to accelerating it.

@safesphere Weyl curvature is gravity, irrespective of whether it is uniform or not, although in the former case, the source of such a curvature would be un-physical . But the definition can be less restrictive than that: a 2+1 D gravity has no Weyl curvature but there are non-trivial metrics to look at. However,  the statement "gravity is not caused by spacetime curvature itself" is simply wrong in any metric theory of gravity

@paul230_x  Are you saying that a uniform Weyl curvature causes gravitational acceleration?

@safesphere The tidal acceleration depends linearly with the total intrinsic curvature (the goedesic deviation equation). Same is true for the relative frame dragging effects between any two test particles. So, yeah as long as there is a non-trivial curvature , even if uniform, there will be such accelerations. But uniform curvature is unphysical because physically we can only realize a localized source of gravity and the curvature produced by it will fall off as one goes further away from it

@paul230_x Thanks for your insight. I’m not an expert in tensor calculus. I’ve thought that the Ricci tensor defines the change of the infinitesimal spacetime volume while the Weyl tensor defines how much this volume is stretched (by the magnitude of the time dilation and length contraction). However, based on your comment, the Weyl tensor must be instead proportional to the gradient of time dilation that causes acceleration. Can you please elaborate?

@paul230_x With no reply do you concede that the uniform Weyl curvature does not create gravitational acceleration? There wouldn’t even be a preferred direction for it. Also please note that I am not talking about the tidal acceleration you mentioned in your comment, but about the gravitational  acceleration described in the equivalence principle.

"Gravitational acceleration" in the absence of tidal forces is simply a matter of not being in an inertial frame.
